# get annotation on method from a CDI managed bean

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cdi

I want to retrieve an annotation (a custom written one) from a method. Usually I can ask the classloader by accessing

```
class.getMethod("methodName").getAnnotation("annotationName")
```

But if the bean is managed by a CDI container (I am using OpenWebBeans) the class is enhanced at runtime. Then I have to use the superclass to ask for annotations. Currently I try to detect if the class is managed by looking for "$$" in the classname. But that seems to be a very dirty solution to me.

Is there any good way to retrieve anntations from a CDI managed bean?

In detail my code is something like that:
I created an annotation "Coolnessfactor" to mark a method to be very cool :-)

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Coolnessfactor {
    CoolnessValue value();
}
```

Via the enumeration CoolnessValue I want to specify how cool the method implementation is.

```
public enum CoolnessValue {
    POOR, VERY_COOL, UNBELIEVABLE;
}
```

Then I mark different methods in my business classe with this annotation, fe:

```
@Override
@Coolnessfactor(CoolnessValue.POOR)
public void getSingleObjectWithDetails(final Integer techId) {
    return this.dao.findCompleteDataByPrimaryKey(techId);
}
```

Now I want to analyse the value of the annotation which marks the different method. I have to do it in a CDI-Decorator, therefore I cannot do it with an interceptor binding.

At the moment my approach is to use the reflection API to retrieve the annotation value:

```
public static <A extends Annotation> Map<String, A> getAnnotatedMethodsOfClass(final Class<?> clazz,
        final Class<A> annotationClazz) {
    final Map<String, A> annotationMap = new HashMap<String, A>();
    Method[] declaredMethods;
    if (clazz.getName().contains("$$")) {
        declaredMethods = clazz.getSuperclass().getDeclaredMethods();
    } else {
        declaredMethods = clazz.getDeclaredMethods();
    }
    for (final Method m : declaredMethods) {
        if (m.isAnnotationPresent(annotationClazz)) {
            annotationMap.put(m.getName(), m.getAnnotation(annotationClazz));
        }
    }
    return annotationMap;
}
```

But this looks very awful to me. Especcially the detection of a class which is enhanced by the CDI implementation is very bad.

Comment: Could you please give more details on what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Could the [`BeanManager`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/enterprise/inject/spi/BeanManager.html) be useful for you?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the annotation on the CDI bean? Maybe (wild guess) a CDI interceptor would be more suitable?

Comment: Very sorry to be not detailed enough. I added some more code details in the question.

Comment: I do not know if the BeanManager helps me in that case. I tried to scan thru the API but found nothing really helpful.

Comment: It isn't exactly clear what you're ultimately trying to achieve (and the answer from Siliarus below even confuses me more because it didn't make sense to me in the context of the question in its current form), but for this specific case I guess your annotation just needs an [`@Inherited`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Inherited.html) to reduce the afwulness.

Comment: Sorry for describing my problem in a crowdy way. I simply want to get the value of an annotation within a CDI decorator. From a decorator I can get the decorated class, but that is only a proxy made by the CDI implementation (in my case OpenWebBeans). On the the proxy class all annotations on methods are removed. That's my problem. Unfortunately the @Inherited is ignored by OpenWebBeans.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try it with `BeanManager` - you will want to use it to get hold of a [`Bean<?>`](https://github.com/cdi-spec/cdi/blob/1.2/api/src/main/java/javax/enterprise/inject/spi/Bean.java#L43) instance of your bean. The approaches differ here, based on what kind of bean it is. Shuffle through the API and find your way.

Once you get `Bean<?>` you should be able to use `getBeanClass()` and with that you gain access to methods and their annotations.